# Databinding an array-valued property in Nancy

Tags: jquery, ajax, data-binding, nancy

I'm sending data to a Nancy module using jQuery post. My data looks like this: `{ a:'b', Items: [{ x:1 }, { x:2 }..]}`. In other words, I use an array of "complex" objects. How do I bind it properly to a strongly-typed model with Nancy? My POSTed data looks like this: `a=b&Items[0][x]=1&Items[1][x]=2`, so I wonder how I create the class that holds the Items list (I can't have a property named "[x]", can I?)

Comment: Is there a reason you can not post a json? The post data you show looks more like a form post data.

Comment: The only reason is that I wanted to simplify my code using $.post instead of $.ajax. I thought it was supported OOTB. If you know how to handle it posting json, please post (he-he) it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure how to do it with `$.post`, so I'm doing it the hard way:

`$.ajax({
    url: '/Media/Editor/SaveCaptions',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: 'application/json'
});`